# BLACK SCREEN Aftern installing new GPU on Ubuntu 20.04 new pc

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, nvidia

Recently I decided to upgrade my Desktop PC, so I bought a few things to try a new setup.
I also decided to keep my 2 hard drives, 1 SSD in which Ubuntu 20.04 is installed, and 1 HDD which I use for storage.
I also kept the PSU a corsair 650 unit.

I did change the motherboard in a new **B450 gaming K4** as well the CPU a **Ryzen 7 3700 X**. I added 2 RAMs  16 GB G-skill and when I tried to put on my GPU, a rather old AMD RX 460, boot started with hiccups.

I decided that after the years the GPU was dying so, I tried to buy a new one.
And so the problem starts:

Seen the astronomical prices of GPUs nowadays, I tried to 'downgrade' a bit, so I bought an Nvidia GeForce GT 1030.
After setting it in the build....
At boot , after Unlocking the hard-drive, which is displayed fine... Black Screen comes up.

Sometimes I get the 3 Ubuntu images GRUB has stored, sometimes goes directly to the Decipher prompt for the HDD.
However .. at any time boot fails, and Black screen is always present.

Any advises?

Thank you all .

Comment: Does Ubuntu boot successfully without any GPU?

Comment: Well , this is something yet to be tested. I assume, that it boots.  Saying assume, because seems I can't use the graphics on the motherboard, so only chance left is the GPU.    However, before the transfer and exchange of parts, on the previous machine, Ubuntu used to run smoothly with no problems.

Comment: In the end I have formatted the drive and reinstalled Ubuntu .   The problem persisted , so , I bought a new PSU.   Seems problem is solved. I also upgraded the PSU in a new 750W modular one.      ==Please close the  thread==